Fix unresolved reference issue without adding dependency in Kotlin and Android Studio
Is there any way to handle "Unresolved reference" issue without adding dependencies for the same.
use case is:-
if dependence is there,then only run the code.

Suppose App A is using a third party lib B.

A single method A_a() have code to call lib B feature.


Now if developer removed the lib the App A, feature will not available as well as method A_a() should not show "Unresolved reference" error.
Is any one have some suggestion for the, Please share.
IOS is handling it like below, is Andorid have any way like this


if dependence is there (properly implemented, placed in proper file etc.), then you will run code without "Unresolved reference"

Actually, I need to do the implementation in a way if we remove the third party lib then app should not show error if lib is added then respected package should work otherwise not.

You would need to have A use reflection to find things in B, rather than having A reference B classes and functions directly. This will be very tedious and error-prone.

Correct but using the reflection Notifier(call back listener of lib) not working
